Is there componentwise descent property of Newton's method
Consider Newton's method for minimizing $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, which is the basically applying it for solving $\nabla f(X)=0$, where $X=(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$.
The iteration of Newton's method is $X^{k+1}=X^k - H^{-1}(X^k)\nabla f(X^k)$ where $H$ is the Hessian matrix $\left[\begin{array}{cc}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\\ \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y\partial x} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\end{array}\right]$.
Now, I know that there is descent property if $H(X^k)>0$ for all $X^k$, since the direction $d^k = -H^{-1}(X^k)\nabla f(X^k)$ is such that $(d^k)^T\nabla f(X^k) = -\nabla^Tf(X^k)H^{-1}(X^k)\nabla f(X^k)<0$. But does this property also hold componentwise?
Like, for each component $d_i^k$ of $d^k=\left(\begin{array}{c} x^{k+1}-x^k\\y^{k+1}-y^k \end{array}\right)$ is it true that the direction $d_i^k$ is descent with respect to its part of the derivative? More generally, if $n>2$ is it true then that $(d_i^k)^T\nabla_{x_i}f(X^k)<0$, where $\nabla f(X^k) = \left(\begin{array}{c}\nabla_{x_1}f(X^k) \\ \nabla_{x_2} f(X^k)\end{array}\right), i=1,2$?
If not so, can one guarantee this with line search somehow?
And also if so, where can I find the proof for this?

Generally, there should be no such descent and there are „globalized“  methods that guarantee this. Let me Look for a source (takes a while)
